# Can't run mjml when installing through CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, mjml

I'm following mjml installation procedures found here: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mjml-cli

which is very straight forward.

After installation, I run ./node_modules/.bin/mjml input.mjml and get "Command line error:
No input files found"

Help!

I'm on mac V10.12.6
Node V8.11.3
npm v6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I installed globally and that seems to work and used "mjml -r index.mjml -o index.html" to compile.